# Jaxb complex xml unmarshall

Tags: java, jaxb

I am having issues to unmarshall nested xml below. Can someone please advise if I am missing something.
`body` tag can contain any Jaxb anotated obj.
Do I have to create a custom adapter for marshalling/unmarshalling such xml?

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<serviceRq xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="serviceRq">
  <body>   
    <createRq>
       <id>1234</id>
    </createRq>
  </body>
</serviceRq>
```

My Jaxb-annotated classes are:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "serviceRq")
public class ServiceRq{    
    private Object body;
    <!-- getters and setters omitted-->
}
```

Here, body can be any jaxb annotated object, in this case its CreateRq.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "createRq")
public class CreateRq{    
    private String id;
    <!-- getters and setters omitted-->
}
```

I am looking for a generic way to support any Jaxb annotated object in body of the input xml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)` and an `XmlAdapter` to handle this use case:

**ServiceRq**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "serviceRq")
public class ServiceRq{    

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=BodyAdapter.class)
    private Object body;
    // getters and setters omitted
}
```

**BodyAdapter**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class BodyAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Body, Object>{

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(Body v) throws Exception {
        return v.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public Body marshal(Object v) throws Exception {
        Body body = new Body();
        body.setValue(v);
        return body;
    }

}
```

**Body**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;

public class Body {

    private Object value;

    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

**CreateRq**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "createRq")
public class CreateRq{    
    private String id;
    // getters and setters omitted
}
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ServiceRq.class);
        System.out.println(jc);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        ServiceRq serviceRq = (ServiceRq) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("input.xml"));

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(serviceRq, System.out);

    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/represent-string-values-as-element.html

Comment: Thanks that worked. Just wanted to add, that I had to add CreateRq to JAXBContext initilization as well to get it working. Thanks for ur help

Comment: If we set lax to false (default behavior), It will create a dom object from the xml content and will not try to map it on a known object?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)` and the `@XmlPath` extension in [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) to handle this use case (Note:  I'm the MOXy lead).  For an approach that would work with any JAXB implementation ([Metro](http://jaxb.java.net/), [MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php), [JaxMe](http://ws.apache.org/jaxme/), etc) see:  [Jaxb complex xml unmarshall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020234/jaxb-complex-xml-unmarshall/6021221#6021221).

**ServiceRq**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "serviceRq")
public class ServiceRq{    

    @XmlPath("body/createRq")
    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    private Object body;
    // getters and setters omitted
}
```

**CreateRq**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "createRq")
public class CreateRq{    
    private String id;
    // getters and setters omitted
}
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ServiceRq.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        ServiceRq serviceRq = (ServiceRq) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("input.xml"));

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(serviceRq, System.out);

    }
}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To use MOXy as your JAXB provider you must include a file named jaxb.properties in the same package as your domain model with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**For More Information**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html