# Using JAXB annotations, how do you get each XML element of a list wrapped in an element, when each list element has an unknown name?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

How is this XML structure modeled in a JAXB class annotation?

```
<root>
 <linksCollection>
  <links>
    <foo href="http://example.com/foo" rel="link"/>
  </links>
  <links>
    <bar href="http://example.com/bar" rel="link"/>
  </links>
 </linksCollection>
</root>
```

Starting with the following root class, what is the Link class? How do you get each link with an unknown element name to be wrapped in the links element?

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlElement
    protected List<Link> linksCollection;
    // etc.
}
```

The following attempt does not work:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "links")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Link {

    @XmlAnyElement
    protected Object link;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String href;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String rel;
    //etc.
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for @XmlElementWrapper ?

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt  with `@XmlAnyElement` for the unknown elements is the right way, but you were missing the `@XmlElementWrapper` for the collection. The following mapping produces a collection for those elements:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="linksCollection")
    @XmlElement(name="links")
    protected List<Link> linksCollection;

}

public class Link {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected Object content;

}
```

According to [this explanation](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jaxbs-xmlanyelementlaxtrue) you will have an instance of org.w3c.dom.Element in your collection if you do not specify a mapping.

If you have only a limited subset of unknown elements, you could change the annotation in the link class as follows:

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "foo", type = FooBar.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "bar", type = FooBar.class) , ...})
protected Object content;
```

The FooBar class could then look like this:

```
public class FooBar {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "href")
    protected String href;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "rel")
    protected String rel;

}
```

However when you can't predict the possible tags, I would stay with the `@XmlAnyElement` and add a `@XmlTypeAdapter`. There is another thread: [Jaxb complex xml unmarshall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020234/jaxb-complex-xml-unmarshall) about this topic.

Comment: Thanks, the @XMLElementWrapper is working.  But, I need more information about mapping classes to unknown elements for @XMLAnyElement(lax=true).  The JAXB context might be out of reach, because it's embedded in a jersey REST client.